# JSP no inserta archivos estáticos

Tags: spring-mvc

Estoy utilizando bootstrap para agregarle diseño a mi proyecto pero al momento de utilizar las librerias no me trae nada de diseño, no se si me explico.

[image: Esqueleto de proyecto]

*Inicio.jsp*

```
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"> -->
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css"> -->
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
      <!-- <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">  -->          

      <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script> -->
      <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
      <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
      <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script> -->          

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">           

      <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
      <script src="/bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/bootstrap/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>          

      <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
      <%@taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>          

      <html>
      <head>
      <body>
      <c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" var="logoutUrl" />
      </body>
      </head>
      </html>
      <html>
      <div class="container" style="margin-left:30%">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse"  style="margin-right:59%" >
        <div class="container-fluid" >
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="inicio">Inicio</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Crear Proyecto </a>      
              </li>

                    <ul  class="nav navbar-nav ">

              <li class="dropdown1">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Mantenimientos </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="listUsuario">Usuarios</a></li>
                  <li><a href="listActividad">Actividades</a></li>
                  <li><a href="listRecurso">Recursos</a></li>
                  <sec:authorize ifAllGranted ="Administrador">
                  <li><a href="listBitacora">Bitacora</a></li>
                  </sec:authorize>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" var="logoutUrl" />
            </ul>


                       <li class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <a style="text-align: right" href="${logoutUrl}" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Cerrar Sesion</a>       
              </li>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
      </div>
      <head>
      <body>          

      </body>
      </head>
      </html>
```

*servlet*

```
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
         xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">           

         <!-- Specifying base package of the Components like Controller, Service, 
           DAO -->
         <context:component-scan base-package="com.csye.SpringMvcSecurity.Controller" />           

         <!-- Getting Database properties -->
         <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />           

         <mvc:annotation-driven />           

         <!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
         <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />           

         <!-- View Resolver -->
         <bean
           class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
           <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
           <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
         </bean>

         <bean id="RecursoDaoImpl" class="com.csye.SpringMvcSecurity.dao.RecursoDaoImpl" />
         <bean id="RecursoServiceImpl" class="com.csye.SpringMvcSecurity.service.RecursoServiceImpl" />

         <bean id="ActividadDaoImpl" class="com.csye.SpringMvcSecurity.dao.ActividadDaoImpl" />
         <bean id="ActividadServiceImpl" class="com.csye.SpringMvcSecurity.service.ActividadServiceImpl" />

         <bean id="BitacoraDaoImpl" class="com.csye.SpringMvcSecurity.dao.BitacoraDaoImpl" />
         <bean id="BitacoraServiceImpl" class="com.csye.SpringMvcSecurity.service.BitacoraServiceImpl" />

         <bean id="UsuarioDaoImpl" class="com.csye.SpringMvcSecurity.dao.UsuarioDaoImpl" />
         <bean id="UsuarioServiceImpl" class="com.csye.SpringMvcSecurity.service.UsuarioServiceImpl" />



         <!-- DataSource -->
         <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
           id="dataSource">
           <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
           <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
           <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
           <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
         </bean>           

         <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
         <bean id="sessionFactory"
           class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
           <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
           <property name="hibernateProperties">
             <props>
               <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
               <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
               <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
               <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
             </props>
           </property>
           <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.csye.SpringMvcSecurity.model"></property>


         </bean>           

         <!-- Transaction -->
         <bean id="transactionManager"
           class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
           <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
         </bean>           

         <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
       </beans>
```

*web.xml*

```
      <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
           version="2.5">

            <display-name>Sample Spring Maven Project</display-name>
            <servlet>
            <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
           </servlet>              

           <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
           </servlet-mapping>              

           <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
           </listener>              

           <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
             /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
             /WEB-INF/security-config.xml,
             /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
             </param-value>
           </context-param>              

           <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
           </filter>              

           <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
           </filter-mapping>              


          </web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente para servir archivos estáticos tienen que estar organizados de alguna forma que el framework (Spring en este caso) lo reconozca. Generalmente Spring busca tus archivos estáticos en:

1. `/META-INF/resources`
2. `/resources`
3. `/public`
4. `/static`

En la configuracion de tu servlet tienes puesto

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

por lo que debes usar el directorio `resources` para los archivos estáticos. Si no lo tienes te lo debes crear dentro de tu `src/main` aunque en lo personal te recomiendo que crees `src/main/resources/public` y los pongas ahí.

Comment: ya pude incluir los css pero los js no funcionan todavia de manera local. que deberia hacer?

Comment: Si sigues el mismo patrón para ubicarlos deberían funcionarte, mira en el navegador que respuesta te está dando el servidor cuando le pides los `js`, en caso de que sea 404 es que están en el lugar que no deberían.